# Remove app icon with NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using the NotificationCompat.Builder to build my notification and I'm pretty much following the guidlines here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

The notification small icon is a small white only version designed to be displayed in Android's status bar.

The problem is that whatever I do the same icon is used to indicate the originating app and I simply want to hide it because my app icon is also the notification big icon

How can I do that (Android 5+)?

- I'm setting the icon with setSmallIcon()

The icon I'm talking about is the notification icon next to the photo here:
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#Anatomy

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should not be using your app icon for the large icon.

The large icon should be used for displaying contextual information specific to a particular notification (e.g. the image of a user who sent your user a message). The small icon is **always** displayed, and accompanies the large icon to indicate which app is displaying the notification.

If you are not using a different large icon, then all you need to do is set the appropriate small icon and Android will only display that icon. Don't let the name "small" fool you- it will be displayed at the normal notification icon size. The only time it is "small" is when you also specify a large icon.

You cannot disable the small icon.

Comment: Completely incorrect and doesn't answer the question. Even in the image here from the official documents you can see the top notification doesn't have that icon. or open the first link and see another screenshot with plenty of these icons. And if you ApiDemos->App->Notification you can see how easy it is to display a notification without the "micro"-icon but I don't want to skip usage of NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: Also, This statement "You should not be using your app icon for the large icon." is also completely incorrect "and contradicts the guidelines: "The notification's icon. The icon symbolizes the originating app. It may also potentially indicate notification type if the app generates more than one type"" .. The icon they are speaking of is the big icon, not the status bar icon. If you set the small icon as the app icon then it's not white only and hence won't be displayed properly in the status bar

Comment: The top notification uses *only* the small icon. The small icon is only "small" when a large icon is present. See the [Required notification documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required) which says exactly what I said- a small icon is mandatory.

Comment: You really don't seem to understand the question. Simply put, there are 3 displayed icons - Big, Small and Status Bar.  The small controls the status both the status and the small. Since status bar icons must be white I don't to use it also in the notification drawer

Comment: In Lollipop, your notification icon will be white (regardless of what coor you make it, the platform will make it white for you), and will be placed over a circular background with a color of your choosing in the notification shade. A small version of this white-on-color icon will always be displayed next to your "large" icon if you provide one. You cannot change this behavior. If you do not like my answer, I'm sorry and you are welcome to provide a bounty on your question to seek additional answers.

Comment: It's not that I don't like your answer, its just wrong. see plenty of apps and even the screenshots from the official documents in the link I provided. 
Also see the demo in ApiDemos .. its not an OS problem and if I skip using the NotificationCompat then I can get the wanted result easly